# ASP.Net WebForms using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication

I'd like to play about with WindowsAuthentication but am seemingly falling  down at the first hurdle.

So I created an empty ASP.Net Webforms app and amended the web.config as so:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <httpRuntime/>

        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Fire up the app and on page load check the following for a value:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

but it returns an empty string (and also shows that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false).

My expectation was to see my windows account name returned e.g. `mydomain\rob`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Using IIS or ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: I was using IIS Express (from VS). Switched to using ASP.Net Dev Server and it works as I expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS, Windows Authentication won't work while Anonymous Authentication is enabled.