# How to implement SSO for Web forms intranet application using AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, authentication, single-sign-on

I am tasked with implementing single sign-on for our customers as part of our next release, the idea is as follows:

- When our customer has access to the website, they won't need to go through an extra login step, because they are already logged into their PC with their AD account and only accounts in AD will have can access the website.

I have tried to research and learn but there seems to be no specific guide.
I'm using web forms and AD in windows server 2019.

Please suggest steps or references to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Windows needs no SSO, it *is* the SSO. All applications run under the account of the user that started them. They connect to other machines, file shares, databases, web sites using that account. To call web sites and services, the site itself would have to allow Windows authentication. On the client you *may* have to set the `Credentials` property of the HttpCliient, WebRequest or WebClient instance you use to `new NetworkCredentials()` without parameters. This will pick up the current user account. That's *FAR* safer than a login form

Comment: `When our customer has access to the website,` you said you have a Windows Forms application, not a web application. What do web sites have to do with desktop applications? And why would an application that's already running under a domain account have to login with an extra step? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, i think I have a little confused, i'ts web form

Comment: Web Forms support Windows Authentication as well. The way to configure this is described in the docs since 2002, as it's the most common authentication method for enterprise networks. You don't need to do a lot - set the proper entries in `web.config` and configure IIS appropriatelly

Comment: In fact, in later Visual Studio versions [you can specify the authentication method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project) in the project creation dialog

Comment: Check [this similar SO queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084243/asp-net-webforms-using-windows-authentication). Apart from setting the authentication method you want in web.config you also need to disable anonymous access in IIS. BTW Web Forms is so OLD it's getting hard to find the correct references in learn.microsoft.com as the first 2000 results are for migrating *away* from Web Forms to MVC, Razor Pages, Core or Blazor

Comment: yes, the web form is really OLD but I am maintaining the existing system in place, and am trying to move from validation form to SSO. But, In the process of searching, I have seen some concepts like ADFS, SAML,... relate to SSO, so Is that one of the solutions to my problem?

Comment: Why do you need any of them? Windows Authentication works. Why would you need anything more if the client is in the domain? Is the client *outside* the domain? Using a browser that doesn't support Windows Authentication? If you don't describe your problem, you can't get an answer.

Comment: *Have* you tried configuring IIS to use Windows Auth? Modified your web.config? Given how common and *old* Windows auth is, perhaps it's *already* configured this way? Or is the question how to allow *multiple* authentication methods, both Forms and Windows?

Comment: Have you tried just googling `"ASP.NET Web Forms" "Windows Authentication"`? One of the first results is [this blog post](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages) that explains how to configure the app and IIS

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LdapAuthentication
{
    public class LdapAuthentication
    {
        private string _path;
        private string _filterAttribute;

        public LdapAuthentication(string path)
        {
            _path = path;
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
        {
            string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

            try
            {
                //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                object obj = entry.NativeObject;

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
                _path = result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public string GetGroups()
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
            search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
            StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
                string dn;
                int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

                for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
                {
                    dn = (string)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                    equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                    commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                    if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                    groupNames.Append("|");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " + ex.Message);
            }
            return groupNames.ToString();
        }
       
    }
}
```